# using multiple vbp files

Tags: dll, vb6

I have inherited a VB6 application written by someone long gone. They created vbps to access DLLs they also created in VB6. These DLLs are referenced through early binding. Isn't there a way to include the vbp files of the dlls in the current project so I can step through all the code and learn what is happening? I swear I did this years ago but don't remember how. Thanks much.

Comment: Are you thinking of a project group? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa232712(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Yes! that is it. Thanks so much...